# Why business rules doesn't work but javascript works to make a field read only in Dynamics-365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I was trying to make field **Default Price List** of **Product** entity to **read only**. I tried to do that from field properties by checking read only but it didn't work. Then I wrote a Business rule which will make the field read only that also didn't work.

Then I wrote a JavaScript code and attached that code in `onLoad` event of Product entity and it eventually worked.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(attrLogicalName).setDisabled(true);
```

Actually I am trying to figuring out why business rules and field properties changes didn't work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior as the Product entity has some OOB scripts locking/unlocking the fields with an `onChange` logic.

Probably Microsoft don't want you to interfere with that OOB implementation by using Business rule. As you said, custom javascript is [the only possible approach](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2017/01/set-default-price-list-field-on-product-as-read-only-in-dynamics-crm/).

[image]